# Mixed XML generated from different sources + PHP Xpath

Tags: php, xml, file, xpath, generated

I'm generating an XML file from many sources. The problem I'm facing right now is that I feed the new XML from a Soap Webservice and from another XML files which are generated by another application. Since the xml from the webservice is returned with a namespace prefix, I need to remove the prefix from the soap webservice or get the namespace prefix from the soap webservice and add it to the XML which is generated by the other application.

For example, from soap webservice:

```
<s:element1></s:element1>
```

From the other application:

```
<element2></element2>
```

And I need to have an xml generated like this:

```
<element1></element1>
<element2></element2>
```

or

```
<s:element1></s:element1>
<s:element2></s:element2>
```

I think the first approach would be easier.

I was thinking on using regex but not sure why it doesn't sound well to me.

I'm using XPath to make the new generated XML file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to remove or change the namespace prefixes. Namespaces are important, prefixes are not. They are just aliases to make the XML easier to read.

The following example show 3 different xmls that all parse to an an element node with the local name `foo` in the namespace `urn:example`.

```
$xmls = [
  '<f:foo xmlns:f="urn:example"/>',
  '<bar:foo xmlns:bar="urn:example"/>',
  '<foo xmlns="urn:example"/>'
];

foreach ($xmls as $xml) {
  $document = new DOMDocument();
  $document->loadXml($xml);
  var_dump(
    $document->documentElement->localName,
    $document->documentElement->namespaceURI
  );
}
```

Output:

```
string(3) "foo"
string(11) "urn:example"
string(3) "foo"
string(11) "urn:example"
string(3) "foo"
string(11) "urn:example"
```

So the information is available in each node. If you import a node into a document it will bring its namespace with it, keeping the information.

```
$xmls = [
  '<f:foo xmlns:f="urn:example"/>',
  '<bar:foo xmlns:bar="urn:example"/>',
  '<foo xmlns="urn:example"/>'
];

$target = new DOMDocument();
$target->loadXml('<f:foo xmlns:f="urn:example"/>');

foreach ($xmls as $xml) {
  $document = new DOMDocument();
  $document->loadXml($xml);
  $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
  $xpath->registerNamespace('e', 'urn:example');
  $target->documentElement->appendChild(
    $target->importNode($xpath->evaluate('/e:foo')->item(0), TRUE)
  );
}

echo $target->saveXml(), "\n\n";
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<f:foo xmlns:f="urn:example"><f:foo/><bar:foo xmlns:bar="urn:example"/><f:foo/></f:foo>
```

For Xpath you have to register your own prefix for the namespace. This can be the same prefix like in the document or a different one. If done correctly the namespace prefix in the document is not relevant:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($target);
$xpath->registerNamespace('e', 'urn:example');
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('count(//e:foo)'));
```

Output:

```
float(4)
```

Comment: Hi ThW, thank you! I think -just think- that I understood what you explained.

But I can't get it working: http://pastebin.ca/3307776

I have defined the namespace in the <element1> element. Do you what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Several things: You did not define the namespace in the source xml, namespaces are URIs, not simple strings and you need to register the prefixes for the Xpath expressions, too. https://eval.in/495445

Comment: I think I need to read more about this subject. Thanks for the efforts and help!